# Keyboard extension size

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-keyboard-extension

I'm making a new iOS custom keyboard and nearly finished with it. But now I got a little problem with the size of the whole keyboard. The keyboard takes half of the whole screen and doesn't have the size of of the normal iOS keyboard. Do you know the reason for this? I didn't set `self.view.frame` in my code and just want to have my keyboard the same size as the normal iOS keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Normal keyboard height is **216px**, please add all the views in one container from your keyboard xib/storyboard and use height constraints of 216px for container. this will solve your problem.

**Happy Coding.**